# Open a link in a specific browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application which runs on all browsers but there is a link to another application which can only run in Internet Explorer. How I can force browser to open this link in a new IE browser when my application running in other browsers such as chrome? Should this piece of code written in server side or client side?

Comment: So anyone not using windows can't access what is on this link? What about [Microsoft  Edge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-10/getstarted-get-to-know-microsoft-edge)?

Comment: In the client-side you can use the this code.
`window.open("microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't force the client to launch a different browser like you're asking.

What I would suggest is to have your application test when it is launched to see if it is currently running in IE.  If it isn't, it should issue an error message stating something like: "This application requires Internet Explorer.  Please reopen in IE."  Then have it stop there.

Comment: @Mahmoud Based on your comment below that your page is the dashboard only, I would suggest checking if the browser is IE on that dashboard page.  You could then use javascript to notify of the requirement when someone without IE clicks the link.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, using resources of JavaScript and HTML5, you cannot run applications on end user's computer. Moreover, it sounds incorrect in terms of security and usability.

The best thing you can do is to write a message like "Open this link in IE" near your link.
At the final page, you can detect a user's browser and, in case it is not an IE, show him a message  "Unfortunately, this web-page works only with IE. Please, open it in IE".

By the way, could you tell us, why your page is not working in other browsers? Probably, we will find a proper answer there.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to run an ActiveX component?

Comment: its not my application. there is another application which forces us to open it in IE and I have not any idea about it. my application is a dashboard which includes many links to different applications.